# How powerful are mobile browsers compared to desktops?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, browser, cryptography

I plan on implementing some client-side hashing (and perhaps encryption) for an application I am building. Using the [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) on a desktop takes *over a minute* to do some of the calculations I'm asking the browser to do in Javascript.

I'm wondering if this is asking too much from mobile browsers like Silk, Mobile Safari, and the others. Apart from testing on most modern smart-phones - is there a general guideline of what is too much for them? Any ratio of how powerful they are to desktop browsers?

Comment: It seems like your question is mostly about calculation time so I don't think your question has so much to do with mobile browsers as it does mobile processors. If I had to guess I'd say whatever you do on a desktop will be around 4x faster than on a mobile device generally speaking.

Comment: If it takes a minute on a desktop (assuming its a fast desktop) this is going to take a huge amount of time on a cell phone. What kinds of things are you doing with this crypto library? I have implemented SHA1 in androids NDK and the performance is pretty good.. Much much better than doing the same thing in Java

Comment: I'm doing many iterations of crypto algorithms in my application for different client side stuff (none of it is related to passwords).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This really depends on your target market. I've recently bought a HTC One X and installed Mozilla Firefox, and the Chrome Beta.... I've tested them both with HTML Canvas based games and it performs surprisingly well.

**#1 Benchmark using:** http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/data/benchmarks/v7/run.html

**Laptop: Dell XPS l502x with i7 2630m, 6 GB RAM. Browser: Google Chrome 18**

```
Score: 8574
Richards: 9362
DeltaBlue: 14903
Crypto: 15677
RayTrace: 13468
EarleyBoyer: 24823
RegExp: 2805
Splay: 4600
NavierStokes: 3096
```

**HTC One X with Quad Core 1.5ghz Tegra 3, 1 GB RAM.  Browser: Google Chrome (Mobile) 18**

```
Score: 1166
Richards: 2595
DeltaBlue: 2147
Crypto: 2227
RayTrace: 1252
EarleyBoyer: 3583
RegExp: 396
Splay: 310
NavierStokes: 502
```

**Conclusion 1.**
This concludes the general JavaScript performance difference between a high end laptop and high end mobile device is approximately 7 to 8 fold.

**#2 Benchmark using:** http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.com/sjcl/browserTest/

**Laptop: Dell XPS l502x with i7 2630m, 6 GB RAM. Browser: Google Chrome 18**

```
Running AES official known-answer tests... passed all 4156 tests. (71 ms)
Running CCM mode tests... passed all 2000 tests. (212 ms)
Running OCB 2.0 mode tests... passed all 22 tests. (16 ms)
Running SHA-256 from catameringue... passed all 513 tests. (53 ms)
Running SHA-256 iterative... passed. (171 ms)
Running HMAC official test vectors... passed all 6 tests. (5 ms)
Running PBKDF2... passed. (38 ms)
```

**HTC One X with Quad Core 1.5ghz Tegra 3, 1 GB RAM.  Browser: Google Chrome (Mobile) 18**

```
Running AES official known-answer tests...passed all 4156 tests. (219 ms)
Running CCM mode tests...passed all 2000 tests. (832 ms)
Running OCB 2.0 mode tests...passed all 22 tests. (23 ms)
Running SHA-256 from catameringue...passed all 513 tests. (191 ms)
Running SHA-256 iterative...passed. (614 ms)
Running HMAC official test vectors...passed all 6 tests. (13 ms)
Running PBKDF2...passed. (168 ms)
```

**Conclusion 2.**
This concludes that when using 'Stanford JavaScript Crypto Library' the performance difference between a high end laptop and high end mobile device is approximately 4 to 5 fold. Also The time in which these tests took on this mobile device are in my opinion acceptable wait times.