# Javascript Support on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, cross-browser

There is a similar question asked in this post:
[Does javascript work on mobile phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538004/does-javascript-work-on-mobile-phones)

The problem is this question was asked in 2009, what are the javascript support for mobile devices nowadays?

Comment: Better than IE8's JavaScript support. The majority of mobile devices are running a version of WebKit mobile. http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Mobile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically as much as you could want. Most mobile phones are running some version of WebKit (what Chrome runs on), so you're pretty much guaranteed better support than IE8 provides if you're developing for mobile.

Edit: What **Joe Tuskan** said. :)

Comment: We are developing mobile sites using ASP.NET and they are being tested on the desktop browsers with IE8, I assume there are mobile devices that still uses IE as their browser?

Comment: @Anna: There might be, somewhere, although such phones are probably rather rare.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript support is very good on modern mobile browsers. The mobile version of Firefox and Chrome provide pretty much desktop-level support for HTML5(CSS3+JavaScript+HTML) features.

**HTML5 Mobile Support**
http://mobilehtml5.org/

**JavaScript Functionality Accross Desktop / Mobile**
http://caniuse.com/#cats=JS_API

It might be also worthwhile stating the impressive JavaScript performance of modern mobile browsers, I recently compared Desktop vs Mobile browser performance see here:
[How powerful are mobile browsers compared to desktops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489901/how-powerful-are-mobile-browsers-compared-to-desktops/10489942#10489942)